# When there are three or four values for distance between cities which to consider?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am making a 10*10 distance matrix which includes distances(only via road) from one city to another. When I search for the distance between two cities, we get, let's say, 100,136,152 for those two cities. To include in the matrix which value I should consider its mean, median, mode, or other, what will be the justification for using that value?
I would be thankful if you could answer my query.

Comment: This depends on what you are using your distance matrix for and how you obtained it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your context. If you are planning to travel between points A and B, you typically have a huge number of possible routes to use (some of which will only differ by a tiny bit). You typically want the shortest one in terms of either distance, or travel time. Potentially with some additional conditions, like avoiding toll roads. Thinking about what you want to use your distance matrix for should help you understand which is the best choice to make.

Comment: My purpose of using distance matrix to use it in mobility model between different cities. You are right that if I may have to actually travel them I may I have considered shortest path or toll. But here my purpose is to define distance matrix such that from a researcher point of view it should be justifiable.

Comment: If I have multiple distances between two cities and I have to represent it by one value what should I do as a researcher point of view and why?